# In Android, parsing Google places URL into a ListView?

Tags: android, json, listview

In my Android app, I'm trying to parse JSON data from a Google Places URL into a ListView. I'm trying to list the names of nearby restaurants. It appears that the parsing works, but I don't know how to grab the "name" variable out of the JSON data. The returned list has items in it that like this:

```
    {"id":
"6217c344be105e............"
{"id":
"2c66bf813799zr2844......"
```

Which to me, looks like it's parsing the "id" variable in the Google Place URL's "results" array. I want it to grab the "name" variable in the "results" array. Can someone show me the correct code to do this? Here's the JSON parsing method that I'm using:

```
    public void parseJSON() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException
{
    String bcURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?"
        + "location=" + latString + "," + longiString
        + "&radius=15000&"
        + "types=restaurant&sensor=false&key="
        + myPlaceKey;

    //--- Get Places URL ----
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(bcURL));
    int statusLine = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if(statusLine == 200){
        HttpEntity e = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
        JSONObject urlData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray resultsArr = urlData.getJSONArray("results");
        int length = resultsArr.length();
        List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            listContents.add(resultsArr.getString(i));
        }

        ListView restListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonList);
        restListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));

    }
    //--- END Get Places URL ----
```

and the listview part of the code:

```
            JSONArray resultsArr = urlData.getJSONArray("results");
        int length = resultsArr.length();
        List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            listContents.add(resultsArr.getString(i));
        }

        ListView restListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.jsonList);
        restListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));

    }
    //--- END Get Places URL ----
```

where does the "get the name variable" bit of code go, and what would that code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/), it should describe everything you need.

Long story short: you need to retrieve from the jsonObject the value you need using `JSONObject.getString("attributeName")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the first object of the JSON file you need to do something like this :

```
        JSONArray samplearr = null;
        samplearr = new JSONArray(String);
       for(int index=0;index<samplearr.length();index++)
      {
        try
        {   
          JSONObject obj = samplearr.getJSONObject(index);

          JSONObject userobj = samplearr.getJSONObject(index).getJSONObject("user");

          Log.d("object","sample array created");
           userobj.getString("screen_name"),
          obj.get("text").toString(),
          userobj.getString("profile_image_url")

      }catch(Exception er)
      {
          Log.d("exceptiom","exception found at : "+er.getMessage());
      }

      }
```

BAsically if you want to grab an object within an object then you do that. According to your question it seems the field you want is inside the "id" field so you have to parse two times through it